# Drawing a visualization of system capacity (pipe flow?)

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

I need to reliably and repeatably visualize a system which is *like pipes that can pass a certain amount of fluid per unit of time*. The real system is a therapy department with several interventions that can provide service to a certain number of people per year, given the capacity of working therapists. Visualization is needed because people respond poorly to just numbers and we are stuck trying to match demand with capacity.

Say there are 3 therapy pathways (assessment, MBT and SCM - in fact there are more, but 3 is a good number for an example). Each has a waiting list, that could be represented by an appropriate size circle before the "pipe" opening. Working therapists represent capacity of a pipe - say 24 people per year or 45 people per year. Patients currently in treatment represent the filling level of the pipe - it can be either saturated or below saturation (by x%).

**Question:** What could be a good visualization for this kind of problem and what R packages could help achieve that?

Many thanks for your advice to busy clinicians. (I have a fair amount of experience with R though)

Comment: Are the 'pipes' not always saturated if there are people waiting before the pipe? I would have thought any queue building up before the pipe only occurs when the system is saturated. I'm also a busy clinician and have used images to explain patient flow through a system to colleagues and managers. I usually use a bathtub analogy, where the rate of the tap pouring in is referral rate, the water going down the plug is the rate of people being discharged, and the level of water in the bath is the number of people in the system - when this exceeds capacity, patients 'spill' (ie get a poor service)

Comment: I fear this question will attract close votes because of its generality, but nonetheless, I think it deserves attention.  My first thought is to use the `igraph` package  ([https://igraph.org/](https://igraph.org/)).  This would allow you to define an arbitrary network of nodes and adges, and to define attributes of each to shw the features in which you are interested.

Comment: Thanks Alex, yes, in the physical world the pipes would always be saturated if there are waiting lists (droplets hanging), but in the people world there are factors - which therapists are suited to do which therapy/pipe and what about those who do groups (as MBT intervention consist of both group and individual once a week) and therapists sometimes go off sick, etc. So every month seeing how full the pipes are is important (100% is best) as is how many people are waiting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do all of this in `ggplot` if you are prepared to manipulate your data to get it into the right shape for plotting. The following took me about 15 minutes.

Let's say your data is like this:

```r
data <- data.frame(service    = c('Assessment', 'MBT', 'SCM'),
                   therapists = c(32, 45, 20),
                   current_patients = c(130, 212, 35),
                   maximum_patients = c(143, 212, 50),
                   queue = c(35, 52, 7))
```

Then you could rearrange it into a plotting format like so:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggforce)

plot_df <- data %>%
  mutate(left_edge = 10 + c(0, cumsum(head(therapists, -1) + 10)),
         right_edge = cumsum(therapists + 10),
         upper_edge = 80 * current_patients / maximum_patients,
         mid = (left_edge + right_edge) / 2)
```

And draw something like the plot you want using ggplot:

```r
ggplot(plot_df) +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = left_edge, ymin = 0, 
                xmax = right_edge, ymax = upper_edge), fill = 'lightblue') +
  geom_segment(aes(x = left_edge, y = 0, xend = left_edge, yend = 80),
               size = 1, color = 'gray20') +
  geom_segment(aes(x = right_edge, y = 0, xend = right_edge, yend = 80),
               size = 1, color = 'gray20') +
  geom_segment(aes(x = left_edge, y = 0, xend = right_edge, yend = 0),
               size = 1, color = 'gray20') +
  geom_circle(aes(x0 = mid, y0 = 100, r = 2 * sqrt(queue)), fill = '#3070B1',
              color = NA) +
  geom_text(aes(x = mid, y = 100, label = queue), 
            colour = 'white', size = 6, fontface = 2) +
  geom_text(aes(x = mid, y = 40, label = current_patients), 
            size = 6, fontface = 2) +
  geom_text(data = data.frame(x = -30, y = c(10, 40, 100), 
            label = c('Therapists', 'Patients\nIn treatment', 
                      'Patients\nWaiting')),
            aes(x, y, label = label), hjust = 0, size = 6, fontface = 1,
            color = '#202040') +
  geom_segment(aes(x = mid, y = 10, xend = left_edge, yend = 10),
               arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.1, 'inches'))) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = mid, y = 10, xend = right_edge, yend = 10),
               arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.1, 'inches'))) +
  geom_label(aes(x = mid, y = 10, label = therapists), fontface = 2) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = plot_df$mid, labels = plot_df$service,
                     limits = c(-30, 140)) +
  coord_equal() +
  theme_void() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 18, color = '#202040'),
        plot.background = element_rect(fill = '#f3f9ff'),
        plot.margin = margin(50, 20, 50, 20))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is just beautiful and this works. I have been envisioning horizontal pipes since patients come in and then get out as well (are discharged once their therapy sessions are complete) in a year's time, but this is great too and it works. In horizontal pipes the water level could be either full (100%) or less than that.